# Count Frequency of a Substring in a String

Tags: c, algorithm, substring, c-strings, function-definition

Given a string T and a pattern P which is also a string. Find the number of occurrences of P in T.

Input

Line 1: contains string P (length is less than or equals to 10^5)

Line 2: contains the string T (length is less than or equals to 10^6)

Output

Write the number of occurrences of P in T

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 5000000
int Count(char T[], char P[])
{
    int count = 0;
    char *pos, *t;
    int index;
    t = &T[0];

    while ((pos = strstr(T, P)) != NULL)
    {
        index = pos - t;
        strcpy(T, T + index + 1);
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
int main()
{
    char *T = (char *)malloc(N);
    char *P = (char *)malloc(N);
    fgets(P, N, stdin);
    fgets(T, N, stdin);
    if (P[strlen(P) - 1] == '\n')
        P[strlen(P) - 1] = '\0';
    if (T[strlen(T) - 1] == '\n')
        T[strlen(T) - 1] = '\0';
    int count = Count(T, P);
    printf("%d", count);
    return 0;
}
```

for this input, I get correct output (10) on my laptop but get 9 as output on website.

Pham Q Dung

cdefghijkmlnoPham Q Dungxyz 1234567890Pham Q Dungijkmlnopqrstuvwxyz 1234567890Pham Q Dunghijkmlnopqrstuvwxyz 1234567890Pham Q Dungfghijkmlnopqrstuvwxyz 123456789Pham Q DungefghijkmlnopqrstuvwxyzPham Q DunghijkmlnopqrstuvwxyPham Q Dung67890Pham Q DungbcdefghijkmlnopqrstuvwPham Q Dungqrstuvwxyz 1234567890Pham Q Dung

Comment: Are you using some kind of "competition" or "judge" site to learn the basics of C? Your code kind of looks like that. Please note that such sites are *not*  any kind of learning or teaching resource to learn basics of anything really. All they tend to teach are bad habits, bad code, and in some cases even *invalid* code. If you're serious about learning programming and C, invest in books and take classes. And once you're comfortable with C, its standard functions, and the common basic algorithms and data-structures, use such sites for leisure, nothing else.

Comment: Case in point: `strcpy(T, T + index + 1);` Using a single overlapping string in [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) leads to *undefined behavior*. And allocating 10 *million* bytes for your strings? Why? Does the assignment requirement really say that, or is it just [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)? There's also no error checking, and there are [better way to remove the newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input) after `fgets`.

Answer (score 0):

This call of `strcpy`

```
strcpy(T, T + index + 1);
```

does not make sense and moreover can invoke undefined behavior.

The source strings shall not be changed within the function,

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
size_t Count( const char s1[], const char s2[] )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    size_t n = strlen( s2 );

    for ( const char *p = s1; ( p = strstr( p, s2 ) ) != NULL; p += n ) 
    {
        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

and called like

```
size_t count = Count( T, P );
printf( "%zu\n", count );
```

And do not forget to free the allocated memory

```
free( P );
free( T );
```